# index 0 each time swipeview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary, swipeview

Index of the index each time is 0 inside:

```
- (UIView *)swipeView:(SwipeView *)swipeView viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    view = [[MTResultCard alloc] initWithFrame:_swipeView.frame];

    NSDictionary *resultsDictionary = [[MTDataLayer sharedDataLayer].results objectForKey:@"mykey"];

    NSString *key = [[[[MTDataLayer sharedDataLayer].results objectForKey:@"mykey"] allKeysSorted] objectAtIndex:index];
    ((MTResultCard *)view).item = [[[MTDataLayer sharedDataLayer].results objectForKey:@"mykey"] objectForKey:key];

    return view;
}


-(NSArray *)allKeysSorted{

    return [[self allKeys]sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString* obj1, NSString* obj2) {
        return [obj1 compare:obj2];
    }];
}
```

Full code can be viewed [here](http://pastebin.com/7NZtXts4)

What would be the reason that each time I have index = 0 ?

Comment: Are you sure `-(NSInteger)numberOfItemsInSwipeView:(SwipeView *)swipeView` does not return `1`?

Comment: @LukasKukacka: Yes, it returns a number different than 0 or 1; a positive one

Comment: What is a SwipeView?  This is not an Apple class.  Is this a delegate protocol method?  Maybe *it* has a problem and it always calling with index 0?

Comment: @RandyJames: Its a custom class that can be found [here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView). Maybe, I am not sure

Comment: Did you implement: `- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInSwipeView:(SwipeView *)swipeView;` ?

Comment: @RandyJames: Yes, that method is implemented

Comment: Sorry... I didn't see your link.  I'm with @LukasKukacka .  I would log/debug what your numberOfItemsInSwipeView is returning to be sure it's *always* returning something > 1.